# Multiple visas, want to switch jobs and countries

Tags: united-kingdom, germany, uk-visa, job-hunting

I have two visa right now one is Tier 2 from UK and other is blue card from Germany, I haven't been to Germany yet.

The problem is after joining in UK I am thinking that the job is not good fit for me and deciding to go to Germany. My UK visa is valid for three months. Do I need to face any trouble to go to Germany and what happens when I want to come and work in Uk in near future?

Comment: I have some trouble understanding how you ended up in this situation. The Tier 2 visa fees are not insignificant and getting these visas takes some time, did you apply for both at the same time, just in case? On what basis did you get your Blue Card? Do you still have a valid job offer? Have you kept your prospective employer on hold?

Comment: I have exempt visa and yes I applied for both as its legal. The blue card is sponsored by the employer, its still not blue card yet because its just a 90days visa and when I will reach Germany I will get blue card. Yes I have valid job offer and they are not on hold just the joining date is after a week.

Comment: Is that you? https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/11612/12159

Comment: @johndoe OK, I just wanted to check, that's what I meant by “keeping your employer on hold” as a specific job offer is a requirement for the Blue Card. And I didn't think applying for both visas would in any way be illegal but I would guess that the costs, timing and hassle would make that rather unusual. In any case, as long as your job offer is still valid and you fully intend to take that job, I would think the German visa is still valid but I don't know more than this.

Comment: Note that having two different visas/residence titles at the same time would be quite common when switching jobs between countries and as such unproblematic. Your situation is a bit different as it seems you haven't been in the UK for long and were not a resident when you applied for the German visas but I am not sure whether this matters.

Comment: @Gala I am not from UK or Germany. The main issue is if I will face any issue while coming to UK in near future? What happens to the visa that is valid for 3 years in UK?

Comment: @mts does that matter?

Comment: @johndoe your exempt visa (which is not, I think, a tier 2 visa) will probably become invalid if you leave the job that qualified you for the exempt visa.  You will need to get a visitor visa to visit the UK after you leave, or a new employer-sponsored visa if you want to return to the UK to take to a new job in the future.  The exempt visa is based on your holding a qualifying job, so if you don't have such a job you should not try to use the exempt visa in any way.

Comment: @johndoe I am aware of that and that's the scenario I was considering, sorry if I wasn't clear. For the time being, Germand and British citizens do not need visas to work in either countries. And like phoog, I assume you would need to apply for a fresh visa to come back to the UK. The main question – in my mind – is whether this would make it more difficult to get such a visa.

Comment: @phoog how will that become invalid? do I need to notify someone before leaving UK?

Comment: @johndoe I do not know whether you need to notify anyone, but your employer probably has to notify UK authorities.  Even if they do not, consider what would happen if you use that visa to travel to the UK.  You will be asked about the purpose of your trip or other circumstances, and those circumstances will not be consistent with an exempt visa.  The exempt visa depends on your job.  If you leave the job, you cannot use the visa, even if the visa has not been officially revoked.  Imagine someone with a diplomatic visa who is no longer employed as a diplomat.  It's the same thing.

Comment: @phoog yes that is what I was most concerned about.

Comment: @johndoe the solution to your concern is simple: before you visit the UK again after leaving your job, *apply for a new visa appropriate to the purpose of your intended visit.*

Comment: Did you ask the [same question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/11612/leaving-job-after-getting-visa) a few days ago?  If so, better to add info to that in hopes of getting a response, rather than doing so as another user.

Comment: You will have to apply for a new visa after you become based in Germany. Whether that visa application for the new visa would be successful is uncertain. Maybe the immigration officials will weigh negatively after you left your previous job, maybe they won't. You'd better ask a different question for that, regarding UK visa application specifically.